# Using the Storyboard in Xcode 4.2.1

Tags: view, header, tabs, controller, storyboard

I'm using the storyboard in a tabbed application that I am currently laying out. In addition to the Tab Bar Controller I have four View Controllers. Do I need a header and body file for each of the views when using the storyboard ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be the best way. That follows the MVC (Model View Controller) design pattern and will get you started going in the right direction.